# How to create an array that infinitely loops a fixed number of elements

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to create a subclass of `Array` (ok, `Array` is `struct`, so I can't do that, but bear with me). The `Array` will have a finite amount of elements (as all arrays do), but it will be impossible to return a `out of range` error, because modulo arithmetic will be applied against any index that gets used to access the array.

```
let loopArray: LoopArray<Int> = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print("Element at position 5 = \(loopArray[5])"
```

If this were a normal array, it would crash with an out-of-range exception. But since it's a loop array the output here would be

```
Element as position 5 = 1
```

I want the array to behave as normal. If a `map` or `filter`, etc operation is performed, it would just perform as expected on the *actual* elements.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an extension that does this:

```
extension Array {
    subscript(loopingIndex loopingIndex: Int) -> Element {
        get { return self[loopingIndex % self.count] }
        set { self[loopingIndex % self.count] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let loopArray = [1, 2, 3]
loopArray[loopingIndex: 5]
```

Since `Array` is a struct, the only way to create a brand new type that does exactly the same thing as `Array` but only the `subscript` is implemented differently is to copy all the code in `Array` except the `subscript`. Therefore, I suggest you writing an extension. The problem with extensions though, is that you must use a subscript with a argument label, since the one without an argument label is already there, in `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by creating a `struct` with one member, which is the `Array`. Then create access methods to access its elements in the way you want.

It should look something like this:

```
struct LoopArray {
    var array: [Int]

    init() {
        self.array = [Int]()
    }

    subscript(index:Int) -> Int {
        get {
            return self.array[index % self.array.count]
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to create wrapper methods for other `Array`'s basic operations.